# Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have simple Rxjs function Observables and Operators to return new Observable.in my code i am using filter and map operators chained inside a pipe sadly, i get error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'. inside filter operator data
The code is following :

```
import { filter, map, Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-observable-operator',
  templateUrl: './observable-operator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./observable-operator.component.css']
})
export class ObservableOperatorComponent{

  title:string='Angular Observable using Observable Operators';

  ob=new Observable((observer:any)=>{
    console.log("Observable Starts");
    observer.next(1)
    observer.next(2)
    observer.next(3)
    observer.next(4)
    observer.next(5)
    observer.complete()
  }).pipe(filter(data=>
    data > 2), //Error inside filter operator (parameter) data:unknown
    map((val)=>{return val as number*2}),

  )

}
```

Comment: pipe( filter( (data: number) => data > 2 )

Comment: I'm most certain that you can simply define `ob=new Observable<number>(...)` and everything else falls into place without `any`s and `unknown`s

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add typing to the param

```
filter((data: any) => data > 2)
```

Comment: yes !! it works Thank you very much

Comment: Ayy! Feel free to hit that checkmark button under points to mark this as the answer, and I get lil extra :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this issue is to define the type of the `observer` right.

The `observer` parameter in the function passed to the constructor of the `Observable` is of type `Observer<number>`, since it notifies numbers. If you do this, Typescript can infer the type of `data` as `number`.

In other words the code should be this

```
ob=new Observable((observer: Observer<number>)=>{
  console.log("Observable Starts");
  observer.next(1)
  observer.next(2)
  observer.next(3)
  observer.next(4)
  observer.next(5)
  observer.complete()
}).pipe(filter(data=>
  data > 2), //Error inside filter operator (parameter) data:unknown
  map((val)=>{return val as number*2}),

)
```